# Why the ideal $\langle x \rangle \subset k[x,y]$ is isomorphic as a graded $k[x,y]$-module to $k[x,y](-1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $S=k[x,y]$ the polynomial algebra over $k$ generated by $x,y$. Let $M$ be a graded $S$-module. Denote $M(a)$ the module $M$ shifted by $a$: $M(a)_d = M_{a+d}$.

On page 2 of [the lecture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/hilbertpresentation.pdf), example 3, it is said that the ideal $\langle x \rangle \subset k[x,y]$ is isomorphic as a graded $k[x,y]$-module to $k[x,y](-1)$.

I am trying to understand this. We have $\langle x \rangle = kx \oplus k Span\{x^2, xy\} \oplus k Span \{x^2y, xy^2, x^3\} \oplus \cdots $. On the other hand, $k[x,y](-1)= k \oplus k Span\{x, y\} \oplus k Span \{x^2, xy, y^2\} \oplus \cdots $. What is the isomorphism $\varphi: \langle x \rangle \to k[x,y](-1)$? Thank you very much.

We also have $k[x,y]= k \oplus k Span\{x, y\} \oplus k Span \{x^2, xy, y^2\} \oplus \cdots $.

Do we have an isomorphism $\langle x \rangle \to k[x,y]$ as graded $S$-modules?

Comment: My guess would be $\phi(r(x,y)x)=r(x,y)$ for all polynomials $r(x,y)\in k[x,y]$. The degree drops by one, so...

Answer (score 3):

The most easily described isomorphism is the map

$$ \langle x \rangle \mapsto k[x,y] : f \mapsto x^{-1}f $$
$$ k[x,y]  \mapsto \langle x \rangle: f \mapsto xf $$

These maps have graded degree $-1$ and $1$ respectively.

If you require morphisms of graded modules to have degree zero, then neither map is even a homomorphism of graded modules. That's why the isomorphism that was stated includes a degree shift.

Comment: thank you very much. Does $\langle x \rangle \to k[x,y](-1)$, $f \mapsto xf$ have graded degree $0$?